# Kendo Angular 2 controls not in npm registry on XAML build

Tags: msbuild, kendo-ui-angular2

Started using angular2 with .NET Core and I'm trying to get continuous integration going on the build servers.

We are running TFS2013 so it's a XAML build definition. Since I don't want the node_modules folder checked in to source control, I'm attempting to run npm install in a powershell script before the build starts.

When I do this I get the following

> npm ERR! 404 Not found : @progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns  npm ERR!
>   404  npm ERR! 404  '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns' is not in the
>   npm registry.  npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
>   (or use the name yourself!)  npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a
>   dependency of 'angular2-webpack'  npm ERR! 404  npm ERR! 404 Note that
>   you can also install from a  npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url,
>   or git url.

On Telerik's site they say you need to enable the NPM registry by running this in the console

```
npm login --registry=https://registry.npm.telerik.com/ --scope=@progress
```

This requires you to provide account details though.

I've done this on the build server and I'm able to run npm install successfully from the command line, but no such luck when attempting it from the powershell script in MSBuild.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The error is most likely caused by the registry not available to the build script.

Make sure that there is a [`.npmrc` file](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc) that specifies the registry and the auth token, not unlike this:

```
@progress:registry=https://registry.npm.telerik.com/
//registry.npm.telerik.com/:_authToken=long_secret_token_here
```

... and that the file is honored by MsBuild.